# query does not return current data

Tags: sql, ejb, postgresql-9.3, netbeans-8

I have a growing project in Netbeans (8.0.2) using Postgresql DB (9,3). My problem is a query that does not return data that is current. I post the data to the DB using either an insert or update query, and I know that works because I can view the table results in the Postgresql pgadmin3 utility. 
However, when I do the following, it returns old data, not the current values:
I am using EJB and session beans, here is code from the HrwattsModelFacade session bean (note the call to em.clear(), that is just my latest attempt to get current data):

```
String ntvqrystr = "SELECT hrwatts_model.*, ";
ntvqrystr += "(SELECT tracks.id FROM tracks where tracks.user_id=?1 and hrwatts_model.track_id=tracks.id) as trkid, ";
ntvqrystr += "(SELECT tracks.starttime FROM tracks where tracks.user_id=?2 and hrwatts_model.track_id=tracks.id) as trkstrt ";
ntvqrystr += "from hrwatts_model order by trkstrt;";
em.clear();
Query qry = em.createNativeQuery(ntvqrystr, HrwattsModel.class);
List<HrwattsModel> qlst;
qry.setParameter(1, usr.getId()).setParameter(2, usr.getId());
qlst=qry.getResultList();
return qlst;
```

I have tried em.clear(), see code above, and the annotation

```
  @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Nothing seems to work except waiting 15-20 minutes, or re-starting glassifsh then I get the current data. Logging out/in (which clears the session) does NOT work!

Comment: Log transaction demarcation (see the PostgreSQL config file for log settings). I wonder if you're using long `SERIALIZABLE` transactions that're seeing old snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any ORM framework like Hibernate or EclipseLink? It looks like caching is the cause (read about second-level catch).